# Jumping on the Clouds HackerRank

Tags: javascript

[image]I want to make a function to return an array with the number of steps it will take to finish another array but with a little condition that i want to take my steps on 0 only and that mean if i have array c = [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0] it will take the first three 0 as one step but if i have just one 0 as you see in the end of the array it will be a step so for this array it will take 4 steps to finish it (0,0,0)(0)(0)(0) as you see it will ignore (1)

This is the link of the test if you want better description 
[HakerRank tets link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/jumping-on-the-clouds/problem?filter=javascript&filter_on=language&h_l=interview&h_r=next-challenge&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_v=zen&page=1&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup)

```js
var array = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
var stepsArray = [];

function jumpingOnClouds(c) {
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i] === 0) {
      if (c[i] === c[i + 1])
        stepsArray.push(c[i + 1])
    } else {
      stepsArray.push(c[i])
    }
  }

  return stepsArray.length

}
var result = jumpingOnClouds(array);
console.log(result);
```

I also have tried this but it keep giving me the same error

```
   var array = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
   var stepsArray = [];
   function jumpingOnClouds(c) {
    for(var i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i++){
        if (c[i] === 0) {
            console.log(c[i])
            if (c[i] === c[i + 1] && c[i + 1] === c[i + 2]) {
                stepsArray.push(c[i + 2])
            } else if (c[i] === c[i + 1]) {
                stepsArray.push(c[i + 1])
            } else {
                stepsArray.push(c[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return stepsArray.length

}
var result = jumpingOnClouds(array);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: According to your requirements, it should be **4** steps for the array you've shown: `(0,0)(0)(0,0)(0)`.

Comment: yes sorry for that mistake

Comment: So, what is your? Are you asking for solution? or is there a bug?

Comment: i ask for solution i have try the solution that i have put on my post but it didn't work

Comment: What is your solution supposed to do? What was your thought behind it?

Comment: Hint: she can only go further by one or two. So if there is a thunder at a certain position, she *has to step* onto the cloud before and after. If there are three non thunder clouds in a row, she only has to step onto the first and the third, if there are four, she has to step onto three of them and can skip one (first, last, and one in the middle), if there are five she can skip two and do it in three steps and so on. Or in your case `Math.floor(3/2) + 1 + Math.floor(2/2) + 1 + Math floor(1/2) = 4`

Comment: to give me back an stepsArray.length with the number of steps i will take to go through the var array you see above so if i take 3 steps , stepsArray.length should be equal 3

Comment: can you explain your solution more

Comment: I think your current solution will work if you increment `i` when there are two consecutive `0` values, add a `i++` statement when the inner `if` condition is meet.

Comment: i think i have done this please check my another solution and see if that what you mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just Added 2 constraints on your solution for the index of `I` and removed unwanted conditions:

I tested my solution on Hackerrank:

Check this out:

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/\s*$/, '')
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.replace(/\s*$/, ''));

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

// Complete the jumpingOnClouds function below.
function jumpingOnClouds(c) {

    var stepsArray = [];
   
    let i=0;
    while(i < c.length - 1){
       
        if ((i+2<c.length) && (c[i+2] === 0)) {
            stepsArray.push(c[i + 2]);
            i+=2;
        } else{
            stepsArray.push(c[i + 1]);
            i+=1;
        } 
        
    }
    return stepsArray.length

}

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

    const c = readLine().split(' ').map(cTemp => parseInt(cTemp, 10));

    let result = jumpingOnClouds(c);

    ws.write(result + "\n");

    ws.end();
}
```

Comment: there is a link for the HackerRank test on the post , that is the problem i try to solve

Comment: @mohamednageh check it now

Comment: it work here but when i try to use it on hackerRank it gave me an error

Comment: @mohamednageh, check this one, I added constraints on I and removed unwanted conditions. Also it passes all test cases on Hackerrank

Comment: @mohamednageh, also it is as per your idea. I just removed last 'else' condition of yours as it will never arrive. You were adding an extra element into your array because of that

Comment: yes this work 

but  why you didn't write stepsArray.push(c [ i ]) in your conditions , i mean our given array might be have [ 1, 0, 1 ] right

Comment: This condition will never arise, as mentioned in the question. There is always a way to reach the end. Now if I can't jump 2 steps, I am ought to jump 1 step. Otherwise I will not be able to reach the end.

Comment: @mohamednageh Check the Hackerrank Constraints, a[0] = a[n-1] = 0. So your test case never arise. Kindly mark the answer correct if I solved all your doubts

Answer (score 3):

```js
function jumpingOnClouds(c) {
  var n = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length - 1;) {
    i += (c[i+2] ? 1 : 2);
    n++;
  }
  return n;
}
```

Comment: that work 
thanks a lot but can you explain me this line 
i += (c[i+2] ? 1 : 2) , i know this is statement but how it work here

Comment: Knowing that we are always want to jump as far as we can and max jump length is i + 2 we are performing a check if c[i+2] !== 0 then we jump 1 step forward otherwise 2 steps

Comment: and two 1 clouds cannot be nearby

Comment: This will throw array out of bound

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that you're using a global variable `stepsArray` to keep track of the steps and you're not clearing the steps after or before each call to `jumpingOnClouds` which means that `stepsArray` will accumulate the steps of each tests.

Second, you need to increment `i` when you get a double `0` step.

Here is a modified working version of your approach:

```js
var array = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0];

function jumpingOnClouds(c) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    if (c[i] === 0) {
      if (c[i] === c[i + 1]) {
        count++;
        i++;
      }
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count;

}
var result = jumpingOnClouds(array);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: that work thanks Titus 
i was trying to get all the result from the old array and put it in new array so that when i get it's length it give me the steps , can you tell me if i want to make the idea i mentioned

Answer (score 1):

That's my solution:

```js
function jumpingOnClouds(arr) {
    let jumps = 0;
    let index = 0;
    const arrLength = arr.length;
    
    while (index < arrLength) {
        const isLastItem = index === arrLength - 1;
        const nextItem = arr[index+1];
        const nextNextItem = arrLength > index+2 ? arr[index+2] : null;
        
        if (isLastItem) {
            index++;
            continue;
        }
        
        if (nextItem === 1) {
            jumps++;
            index = index + 2;
            continue;
        }
        
        if (nextItem === 0) {
            if (nextNextItem === 0) {
                jumps++;
                index = index + 2;
            } else if (nextNextItem === 1 || !nextNextItem) {
                jumps++;
                index++;
            }
            continue;
        }
    }
    return jumps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The easiest way

```
const recCloud = clouds => {

    if(clouds.length < 4)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1 + recCloud(clouds.slice(clouds[2] == 0 ? 2 : 1));
};
```

> or even

```
const recCloud = clouds => {
    return clouds.length < 4 ? 1 : 1 + recCloud(clouds.slice(clouds[2] == 0 ? 2 : 1));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const jumpingOnClouds = (clouds) => {

    let jumpCount = 0;
    let currentCloud = 0;

    while (currentCloud < clouds.length-1) {

        // There are only two ways to jump. Either jump two clouds away or one 
        // cloud away from the current position

        // Check if next 2 clouds are "cumulus" which values are 0s
        // If they are cumulus then jump to 2 clouds away from the current cloud
        // else jump 1 position away from the current cloud
        // Since you jump on both cases, you just have to increment the number 
        // of jumps by 1.

        if (clouds[currentCloud + 2] == 0) {
            currentCloud += 2;
        } else {
            currentCloud ++;
        }
        jumpCount++;
    }
    return jumpCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int jumpingOnClouds(vector<int> c) 
  {
    int n;
    n=c.size();
    int count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
     count++;
     if (i<n-2 && c[i+2]==0) i++;
    }
     return count;
  }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Java. Passed all test cases given.

```
static int jumpingOnClouds(int[] c) {
    int jump = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    while (pos < c.length) {
        if (pos + 2 < c.length && c[pos + 2] == 0) {
            pos = pos + 2;
            jump++;
        } else if (pos + 1 < c.length && c[pos + 1] == 0) {
            pos = pos + 1;
            jump++;
        } else
            break;
    }
    return jump;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking same in **Java**

```
        int jumpcount=0;
        for(int i=0; i<c.length-1;){
            if(c[i]==0){
                if(i+2<c.length && c[i+2]==0){
                    jumpcount++;
                    i+=2;
                }else if(c[i+1]==0){
                    jumpcount++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int jumpingOnClouds(int c_count, int* c) {
    int i=0,jump=0;
        
    while(i<c_count-1){
        
        if(*(c+i+1)==0 && *(c+i+2)==0){
            jump++; i+=2;
        }
        else if((*(c+i+1)==0 && *(c+i+2)==1) || *(c+i+1)==0){
            jump++; i++;
        }
        else if(*(c+i+1)==1 && *(c+i+2)==0){
            jump++; i+=2;
        }
        else 
            break;
    }
    return jump;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int jumpingOnClouds(int[] c) {
        int num_jumps = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < c.length - 1) {
            if (i + 2 == c.length || c[i + 2] == 1) {
                i++;
                num_jumps++;
            } else {
                i += 2;
                num_jumps++;
            }
        }
    return num_jumps;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Php solution to jumpingclouds

```
    function jumpingOnClouds($c) {
        $count = 0;

        for ($i = 1; $i < count($c); $i++) {
            $a =  $c[$i];
            if ($a == 0) {
                if ($a === $c[$i + 1] && $a === $c[$i - 1]) {
                    $count++;
                    $i++;  
                } else {
                    $count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return $count;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could explain why this is the solution and not only post some code?

Comment: by default the first value in the array would always would be 0 so i skipped it, then i checked if the current value is equal to the next value in the array or equal to the previous value then i increase the count and the index count if not i only increase the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
    'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function(inputStdin) {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function() {
    inputString = inputString.split('\n');

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

/*
 * Complete the 'jumpingOnClouds' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY c as parameter.
 */

function jumpingOnClouds(c) {
    // Write your code here
    let jumpCount = 0;
let step = 0;
for(let i=0; i<c.length; i){
if(c[i] === 0 && i !== (c.length - 2)){
i = i + 2;
jumpCount++
} else if (c[i] === 0 && i === (c.length - 2)){
i = i + 1;
jumpCount++
} else {
i = i - 1;
}
}
return jumpCount - 1;

}

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const n = parseInt(readLine().trim(), 10);

    const c = readLine().replace(/\s+$/g, '').split(' ').map(cTemp => parseInt(cTemp, 10));

    const result = jumpingOnClouds(c);

    ws.write(result + '\n');

    ws.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = new []{0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0};
        int k = 2;
        MyHackerRankCode(arr,k);
        BestHackerRankCode(arr,k);
    }
    private static void BestHackerRankCode(int[] c, int k)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int E = 100;
        int n = c.Length;
        do {
            E--;
            i = (i + k) % n;
            //Console.WriteLine(9%10);
            if (c[i] == 1)
                E -= 2;
        } while (i != 0);
            
        Console.Out.WriteLine(E);
    }
    private static void MyHackerRankCode(int[] c, int k)
    {
        int counter =0;
        int resultEnergy =100;
        int prev = 0;
        do
        {
            prev = counter;
            counter += k;
            if(counter > c.Length-1)
            {
                counter = k - ((c.Length-1) -prev) -1 ;
            }
            if(counter == 0)
            {
                if(c[0] == 1)
                    resultEnergy = resultEnergy - 1 - 2;
                else if(c[0] == 0)
                    resultEnergy = resultEnergy - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if(c[counter] == 1)
                    resultEnergy = resultEnergy - 1 - 2;
                else //if(c[counter] == 0)
                    resultEnergy = resultEnergy - 1;
            }
        }
        while(counter !=0);    
        //return resultEnergy;
        Console.WriteLine(resultEnergy);`enter code here`   
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding supporting information to explain your answer, or trimming it down to just the important part.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution:

```js
function jumpingOnClouds(c) {
  let jump = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i++) {
    if (c[i + 2] == 0) {
      jump = jump + 1;
      i = i + 1;
    } else
    if (c[i + 1] == 0) {
      jump = jump + 1;
      i = i + 0;
    }
  }
  return jump;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            function jumpingOnClouds(c) {

                let jumps = 0;
                for (let i = 0; i < c.length - 1; i++, jumps++) {
                if (i + 2 < c.length && c[i + 2] == 0) {
                    i++;
                }
                }
                return jumps;
            }
```

Comment: Hi, please try to add some [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). Only-code answers may address the question, but  are not particulary useful to others

Comment: Please add some explanation and reformat your code.